# Sigma bc 1609 kmh flashing but not counting

Tags: bike-computer

I've just presented a new Sigma BC 1609 (wireless), assembled, put the sensor on the fork and a magnet on a spike, set the wheel size, looks fine.
But the speedometer does not work - it is just flashing?
Any hints?

Thank you.

**update**
replied the question

Comment: You've to "marry" the transmitter and receiver -- go through a little "ceremony" to get them to recognize each other.  There will be a procedure for this in the instructions.  (That said, the first wireless Cateye I got was no good and I had to return it for a replacement.  Wireless is still not all that reliable.)

Comment: Thank you. I found out that the gap was just too big between sensor and the magnet. It is ok now.

Comment: Alex, on Stack Exchange sites, it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. Do you want to take your update and making it an answer?

Comment: I wanted to, but yesterday could not because of the novice limitation (not allowed to reply your own question in under 8 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update After watching the installation video on the Sigma web-site, understood that the gap was too big between sensor and the magnet. So the sensor shouldn't parallel to the wheel, but pointing towards it -